# Laravel Route not displaying page properly

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm currently learning Laravel, very new to it.

I have two routes setup like so:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});
```

In the 'pages.about' file I've inputted an `<h1>` with some random text to test it, however, when I navigate to that page in localhost all I get is a white page with the number '2' displayed. No errors, just '2':

[image: display page]

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

File-tree if needed:

[image: file-tree]

**EDIT**

about.blade.php:

```
kjnksjndkjnsdc
<h1>ijsoijsoijs</h1>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210716/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-knights-laravel-route-not-displaying-page-prope).

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute command php artisan view:clear and php artisan route:clear

Answer (score 1):

instead of return view just echo something like

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    //return view('pages.about');
     echo "laravel";
});
```

check it again using ctrl+f5 key if there any cache issue is same result show then change the method from get to post again try it 
if it shows properly the echo then go to your about page and give the proper html structure

Comment: I'm using a mac btw, tried ctrl+f5 and it didn't do anything

Comment: i am actually using pc in mac cmd+R may work like instant temp cache cleaner in reload but i am not sure you can try it and as it is shown that means your routing is good reconstruct your about page then you will see your expected result and it will more good if you use controller for load the view file

Answer (score 1):

Route is ok. Folder structure is ok too. 
Is this a blank project? Did you change someting in some other folders?

Because I try this on my PC and works fine

Comment: I've changed a file in xampp called 'httpd-vhosts.conf'. Could that have changed anything?

Comment: How you use this project with Apache or with embeded laravel server?
Laravel server you can start in console with "php artisan serve"

Comment: I'm using the Laravel server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was but I reset the project from scratch and it's now working. Luckily, I wasn't too far in to delete the entire project.